# C# Flash - ExternalInterface

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, flash, externalinterface

We are hosting the ActiveX control in a WinForms application to embed flash.

Is there a good way to get the list of visible ExternalInterface functions that are available for any given swf file?

We are working with a 3rd party swf file, and do not have access to source.

If it's not possible from C# (or code), is there a tool out there that can do it?

ANSWER:  The only way I've found is to use a flash decompiler and then look for the line:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("methodName", methodName);
```

I'm marking the top answer as the answer for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Flash does not expose its external interface "API" to the environment.

Comment: So is the only route something like a flash decompiler?  I have just seen other applications that are interacting with this particular swf the same way that we want to, so I expect there are ExternalInterface calls to do this.

Comment: Either that, or the developers of such other applications asked the 3rd party for documentation. That seems to be the logical explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use event FLASH_CALL on your Flash ActiveX object and decode XML like:
[this example](http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/communicate-betwen-c-and-an-embeded-flash-application/).